# java DataBase class

Tags: java, arraylist, types, hashmap

I am trying to make some `DataBase` class. I know that I want each column to be represented as ArrayList. 
I want to create Constructor as that

```
DataBase(String[] columnNames, String[] types)
```

so for example

```
DataBase({"Column1","Column2","Column3"},{"int","string","myOwnType"})
```

I tried to make it with HashMap which will have column name as key and ArrayList as value.

This is what I got so far.

```
public class DataFrame {

    public HashMap<String, ArrayList> data;
    public String[] names;
    public String[] types;

    public DataFrame(String[] names, String[] types) {
        data = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();
        nazwy = new String[_names.length];
        typy = new String[_types.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < _names.length; i++) {
            ArrayList column = new ArrayList<>();
            data.put(_nazwy[i], column);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I create a column of type given in program? I thought about creating ArrayList and then make Map which will have label and that list, but I cant find how to do that.

Comment: Is it a good idea to implement an in-memory database engine? Is this for your PhD thesis? Because otherwise I would recommend you use one of the free ones that somebody else already spent years creating.

Comment: I know who to make it working only for one type. But how to do that so every column has type specified in constructor?

Comment: yes, its for my PhD :/

Comment: It's hard to tell whether this is a good idea. For a start, this seems to meet the concept of table, not that of a database. Also, it depends a lot on your usage pattern (how you'll be updating and querying your data). So, as @mypetlion said, use an existing solution (such as H2).

Comment: Unfortunetely I need to make this on my own. I made this working when I specify type in implementation, but is there a simple way to create a proper ArrayList<type> from the string[] types?

Answer (score 0):

In your method, this Loop is re initializing the arraylist so it is not possible to store the records.

```
for(int i = 0; i < _names.length; i++) {
        ArrayList column = new ArrayList<>();
        data.put(_nazwy[i], column);
    }
```

Always good to have List. Map will represent each records with column names so that it will easy for processing.

```
     ArrayList list = new ArrayList(50);
     HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
        for(int i=1; i<=columns; ++i){           
              row.put(getColumnName(i),data(i));
        }
        list.add(row);
```